# URL Rewriting - Names to numbers (Apache)

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

Is it possible to do a URL rewrite where a url like http://www.myurl.com/usa/california/sanjose redirects to http://www.myurl.com/c=1&st=3&area=14

The problem here is, all this time we've used urls like http://www.myurl.com/c=1&st=3&area=14 All areas states and countries are represented by numbers in the database. So in the above example if usa/california/sanjose redirects to c=1&st=3&area=14, if a user typed usa/florida/tallahassee he'll have to be redirected to c=1&st=5&area=3. The numbers change depending on the country, state and city.

Can URL Rewriting change names to numbers automatically depending on the name, or will we have to update the database and change all numbers to names so that the php file can draw data based on names instead of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can rewrite based on name, but that will be one hell of a ruleset (you'll need to rewrite every state name, every country name, and every region accordingly - basically all your database).
2. Don't you have country and state names in database as well? I would suggest you getting names, translating them to ids, and then working with ids like you did before (which is preferred).

Ruleset to translate the nice url to parameters:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /?country_name=$1&state_name=$2&area_name=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) /?country_name=$1&state_name=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) /?country_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

First rule rewrites all threee params, second country and state and third - only country
You can even point this to other file (not your regular index) and then after translating the parameters to IDs - include the original handler

Comment: In the end, we decided to update the db with country, city and area names corresponding to their numbers. Then we did an htaccess file with rules somewhat similar to what you suggested. Everything seems to be working fine for now.